# Calling a helpers' method, from a function, in a view

Tags: function, oop, object, cakephp-1.3, this

In a view, I've created a function that masks some repeating helper calls.
The problem is that it can't use the $this variable, since it's not in a context. the error is:

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context
```

1. How can I override it?
2. What is the context in the view? is it the view class?

it's cake 1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that it is impossible, it's a language restriction.

The solution was to call the class itself, by using `HelperName::method_name()` from within the function.